# After a pipe() and fork(), why does close(fd[1]) in the parent close the *child's* fd[1]?

Tags: c

In the parent process `close(fd[1]);`,
why it will skip the first fd[1] (replaced parent STD_OUT) and close fd[1] at child process ?

```
#define STD_INPUT 0
#define STD_OUTPUT 1
```

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd[0]);

if(fork()!=0){
    // parent process
    close(fd[0]);
    close(STD_OUTPUT);
    dup(fd[1]);
    close(fd[1]);
    excel(process1, process1, 0);
}
else{
    // child process
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
It will have 2 fd[1] after `dup(fd[1];`,
why the system closed the second fd[1](4. [write]) in the result? not first fd[1](2. [write])?

start fork
1. STD_IN
2. STD_OUT
3. [read]
4. [write]

result
1. STD_IN
2. [write]
3. -close-
4. -close-

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: update on the post.

Comment: Please try to select titles that summarize your question. The original "System Call for File Management" could be about... well... almost anything. It would also be helpful here to have a *true* [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* code that clearly demonstrates the issue when compiled and run without changes. Building a standalone reproducer also tells how you're measuring behavior, which makes it possible to find errors in the diagnostic process.

Comment: Use the standard names `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDIN_FILENO` for the standard file descriptors.  Use `dup2(fd[2], STDOUT_FILENO)` to simplify life.

Answer (score 2):

> It will have 2 fd[1] after dup(fd[1];,

No. The value of `fd[1]` never changes. If it was 4 before the call to `dup`, it's 4 after the call to `dup`.

> why the system closed the second fd[1](4. [write]) in the result? not first fd[1](2. [write])?

If `fd[1]` is 4, then `close(fd[1]);` will close descriptor 4. It will not affect any other descriptors that happen to reference the same endpoint.

Before you call `pipe`, your process already has file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 as its standard input, standard output, and standard error. You then create two new descriptors for the pipe.

So this is what it looks like when you call `fork`, more or less:

> ...0...|....1....|.....2....|....fd[0]....|.....fd[1].....
>   stdin, stdout, stderr, pipe end, other pipe end

Then, in the parent, you close `fd[0]`, so you have:

> ...0...|....1.....|.....2...|....fd[0]................|......fd[1].....
>   stdin, stdout, stderr, closed pipe end, open pipe end

Then you close stdout:

> ...0....|...1....|.....2.....|...fd[0]..|......fd[1].....
>   stdin, closed, stderr, closed, open pipe end

Then you dup the open pipe end:

> ...0....|..................1.............|.....2.....|..fd[0]..|.......fd[1].....
>   stdin, dup of open pipe end, stderr, closed, open pipe end

Then you close fd[1]:

> ...0....|....................1............|.....2...|...fd[0]..|..fd[1].....
>   stdin, dup of open pipe end, stderr, closed, closed

Or, more simply:

> ...0...|...................1...............|....2....
>   stdin, dup of open pipe end, stderr

So when you call `execl`, the new process will inherit the parent's standard input and standard error but will inherit a copy of one end of its pipe as its standard 
output.